# Scalar Field of a long thin wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Given the situation that $B=-\nabla A$ where B is magnetic field and A is some Scalar Field. How can I calculate the scalar field, A.

We are dealing with current free region, here.

I know we can calculate B for a infinitely long thin wire given $I$. But I am not sure how we can calculate $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get $B$, then 
$$A(\vec{x}_1)-A(\vec{x}_0)=\int_{\vec{x}_0}^{\vec{x}_1}\vec{B}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$$
This is usually done by setting some value to the potential at a particular point from the information provided. Be careful, even though a typical choice is to set $A=0$ at infinity, you can't do that in this case because your wire is infinite.

Comment: thank you for the response. One of my prime concerns was is the formula for B is $\frac{U_0I}{2\pi R}$ dependent on whether we are dealing with current free cases or not?